# updating array object in redux phrasing error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, redux

I am trying to update an array object in react.js by accessing the index of the object.
I have written this code and am getting this error.

> Parsing error: ',' expected.eslint

```
            updateUserAvatar: (
          state,
          { payload: { id, avatar } }: PayloadAction<UpdateUserAvatar>
        ) => {
          const users = current(state.data.familyMembers)
          const user = users.find((user) => user.id === id) as DashboardFamilyMember
          const userIndex = users.findIndex((user) => user.id === id)
          return {
            ...state,
            data: {
              ...state.data,
              familyMembers: [
                ...state.data.familyMembers,
//where error occurs
               userIndex: {
                  ...user,
                  avatar: avatar,
                },
              ],
            },
          }
        },
      },
```

I know I can map through the array but I am confused as to why this doesn't work.

Comment: are you sure that, `userIndex` should be in side `familyMembers ` array?

Comment: Yes I am trying to access these objects https://imgur.com/512453p

Answer (score 0):

You can map over familyMembers array and update when you find user.id and update that avatar.

```
const users = current(state.data.familyMembers)
const familyMembers = users.map(user => {
    if(user.id === id) {
       return { ...user, avatar };
    } else {
       return user;
    }
}
const userIndex = users.findIndex((user) => user.id === id)
return {
  ...state,
  data: {
     ...state.data,
     familyMembers: familyMembers,
   },
};
```